# What are the reasons behind having a maximum of 5 tags per question?

Tags: discussion, tags, questions

Why not just have 1 tag or 3 tags? Or have 10, 20 or 30?

Comment: Why is the drinking age in many states in the US 21 and not 20, 18, 25 or 30? It's just an arbitrary limit you have to draw a line somewhere.

Comment: @Kop Most arbitrary limits have some reasons behind them. Even if these reasons are not of most importance. 5 probably wasn't chosen by dice roll... or was it ?

Comment: @DrDro: it was probably chosen over 10 because 10 is too many tags, and over 4 or 6 because it's a nicer number

Answer (score 30):

`[some]` `[users]` `[already]` `[abuse]` `[tags]` `[pretty]` `[badly]` `[and]` `[allowing]` `[more]` `[would]` `[only]` `[make]` `[things]` `[worse]` `[.]` `[besides]` `[,]` `[there]` `[should]` `[be]` `[some]` `[kind]` `[of]` `[limit]` `[right]` `[?]`

Answer (score 8):

I think it was to prevent under-categorizing and over-categorizing. With fewer than 5 tags you're hurting the visibility for the subject. I can ask a question that encompasses `[java]`, `[maven]` `[maven-repositories]` `[java6]` and `[best-practice]` and have those all be legitimate tags for the subject that I'm asking about. It's helpful for people searching/subscribing to a tag and for other generic searches. Limiting it would hurt searchability of a question.

More than 5 and most questions end up being shotgun tagged to abuse its visibility. Many times on SO I see questions tagged with the top 5 most discussed languages when they really only vaguely talk about them (and a `[language-agnostic]` tag would be better or don't even talk about them at all). Expanding it would only lead to abuse.

So why 5? Because it strikes a nice balance.

Comment: [best-practice] is not an allowed tag http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/

Comment: @Jeff Opps, I forgot.

Answer (score 2):

Screen Space.

Comment: The final frontier.

Answer (score 0):

The real answer here is obvious: it's a limitation. Either cost-savings or otherwise. I don't believe the SQL back-end handles these very well.

There are certainly a lot of cases where this matters, take for instance on dba.stackexchange.com. Because we don't have hierarchical tags we tag versions. Something like [PgAdmin](https://www.pgadmin.org/) is a tool that itself has a version. PgAdmin 4 was a total rewrite of PgAdmin 3. PgAdmin itself connects to PostgreSQL. PostgreSQL has its own version.

- So we have `[pgadmin]`, and `[pgadmin-4]`. Both of which could be applicable.
- And, we have `[postgresql]` and `[postgresql-9.2]`. Both of which could be applicable.

Let's say now you're working on a problem that involves spatial clustering. Well now you pick,

- `[spatial]`
- `[postgis]`
- `[index]`